# Swift - Maintaining decimal point with Editing Changed

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a unit converter and want all the units to update simultaneously as the user enters a value. e.g. entering 25 into the 'cm' field will automatically display 250 in the 'mm' field and 0.25 in the 'metre' field.

This is so far working great using **Editing Changed** event so long as the user enters whole numbers, as soon as a decimal is entered iOS automatically strips the decimal away to format the UITextField as a whole number since it is formatting after each keypress and assumes the the number entered ends with a decimal point i.e "25." which then becomes "25" instead of "25.0".

For instance entering 25.6 will display as 256.

Is there any way to prevent this automatic formatting? The only solution I have found is to link the event to **Editing Did End** but this is not ideal as the other units will only become updated after the user finishes entering the value and not updated automatically as I require.

The code I'm using to convert from string to double is as follows:

```
@IBAction func editMm(sender: AnyObject) {
        var setToDouble:Double? = stringToDouble(textFieldMm.text)
        valueEdited(setToBase!)
}

func stringToDouble(inputString:String) -> Double{
    // this removes the comma separators which are automatically added to the UITextField during formatting
        var formattedString = inputString.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(",", withString: "")
        var doubleResult:Double = (formattedString as NSString).doubleValue
        return doubleResult
}
```

I've tried to catch this in the `stringToDouble` function but it seems the formatting happens before the value reaches that point in the code.

Comment: didn't my code solve the problem?

Comment: Yes it did thanks. I've had to change the way my app works to accommodate it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` function in `UITextFieldDelegate`. The `newString` will contain the current string while editing.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    let newString = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
    println(newString)

    return true
}
```